# How to check if specific executable has a live process for specific user in bash?

Tags: bash, git-bash

I'm trying to check if specific executable has a live process for specific user, so I tried:

```bash
lsof $(which python3) -u username
```

and its not considering the `-u`

I'm getting a list of all python live processes for ALL of the users

I also tried use `-a` but its not working.

Comment: `lsof` just scans procfs; you can of course do that yourself.

Comment: (...if you want to ask a question about using standard UNIX tools, instead of about writing code, then [unix.se] is the better place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `lsof` doesn't work, you can always reimplement it yourself.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- MUST be bash, not sh

user=nobody
target_exe=/usr/bin/python3

while IFS=' ' read -r -d '' proc_name exe_link; do
  pid=${proc_name%/exe}
  if [[ $exe_link = "$target_exe" ]]; then
    echo "$pid"
  fi
done < <(
  find /proc -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 \
    '!' -user "$user" -prune -o \
    '(' -name exe -path '/proc/[[:digit:]]*' -printf '%P %l\0' ')')
```

Note that, for this tool as well as for `lsof` itself, you need to be running with enough permissions to access the relevant content in procfs.